# jQuery datepicker years shown

Tags: jquery, datepicker

With the jQuery datepicker, how does one change the year range that is displayed?  On the jQuery UI site it says the default is "10 years before and after the current year are shown".  I want to use this for a birthday selection and 10 years before today is no good.  Can this be done with the jQuery datepicker or will I have to use a different solution?

link to datepicker demo: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year

Answer (score 165, accepted):

If you look down the demo page a bit, you'll see a "Restricting Datepicker" section. Use the dropdown to specify the "`Year dropdown shows last 20 years`" demo , and hit view source:

```
$("#restricting").datepicker({ 
    yearRange: "-20:+0", // this is the option you're looking for
    showOn: "both", 
    buttonImage: "templates/images/calendar.gif", 
    buttonImageOnly: true 
});
```

You'll want to do the same (obviously changing `-20` to `-100` or something).

Comment: Thank you!  I looked through there but must have missed it.  It works perfectly.

Comment: I'm trying to use this but it's only showing -20 years from the currently _selected_ date...?

Comment: You can also use `c` instead of `+0`, so `yearRange: "-20:c",`

Answer (score 39):

Why not show the year or month selection boxes?

```
$( ".datefield" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange:'-90:+0'
});
```

Comment: probably should be quotes around the yearRange.

Comment: this is exactly what Im looking for.. thank you sir.. changeMonth , changeYear

Answer (score 10):

what no one else has put is that you can also set hard-coded date ranges:

for example:

```
yearRange: "1901:2012"
```

whilst it may be advisable to not do this, it is however, an option that is perfectly valid (and useful if you are legitimately looking for say a specific year in a catalogue - such as "1963:1984" ).

Answer (score 6):

Perfect for date of birth fields (and what I use) is similar to what Shog9 said, although I'm going to give a more specific DOB example:

```
$(".datePickerDOB").datepicker({ 
    yearRange: "-122:-18", //18 years or older up to 122yo (oldest person ever, can be sensibly set to something much smaller in most cases)
    maxDate: "-18Y", //Will only allow the selection of dates more than 18 years ago, useful if you need to restrict this
    minDate: "-122Y"
});
```

Hope future googlers find this useful :).

Comment: Oldest person is Jeanne Calmant and was 122 years old. I would put it to 140 to keep some margin :)

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy You are correct, I think I was thinking of the oldest person alive...who is now 116 :). Answer edited.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to what @Shog9 posted, you can also restrict dates individually in the beforeShowDay: callback function.

You supply a function that takes a date and returns a boolean array:

```
"$(".selector").datepicker({ beforeShowDay: nationalDays}) 
natDays = [[1, 26, 'au'], [2, 6, 'nz'], [3, 17, 'ie'], [4, 27, 'za'], 
[5, 25, 'ar'], [6, 6, 'se'], [7, 4, 'us'], [8, 17, 'id'], [9, 7, 
'br'], [10, 1, 'cn'], [11, 22, 'lb'], [12, 12, 'ke']]; 
function nationalDays(date) { 
    for (i = 0; i < natDays.length; i++) { 
      if (date.getMonth() == natDays[i][0] - 1 && date.getDate() == 
natDays[i][1]) { 
        return [false, natDays[i][2] + '_day']; 
      } 
    } 
  return [true, '']; 
}
```

Comment: what's wrong with the syntax highlighting here? and what's the deal with nationalDays? I don't understand your code sorry, if you could clarify?

Answer (score 3):

```
 $("#DateOfBirth").datepicker({
        yearRange: "-100:+0",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
    });
```

yearRange: '1950:2013', // specifying a hard coded year range
or this way

yearRange: "-100:+0", // last hundred years

It will help to show drop down for year and month selection.

Answer (score 2):

au, nz, ie, etc. are the country codes for the countries whose national days are being displayed (Australia, New Zealand, Ireland, ...). As seen in the code, these values are combined with '_day' and passed back to be applied to that day as a CSS style. The corresponding styles are of the form show below, which moves the text for that day out of the way and replaces it with an image of the country's flag.

```
.au_day {
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background: #eee url(au.gif) no-repeat center;
}
```

The 'false' value that is passed back with the new style indicates that these days may not be selected.

Answer (score 1):

i think this may work as well

```
$(function () {
    $(".DatepickerInputdob").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "d M yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '1900:+0',
        defaultDate: '01 JAN 1900'
    });
```