# How can i set Year range for a jQuery Date Picker: 1900 to current year, or 1900 to 9999

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

Hi all i used the `Jquery Date picker` which works well enough for me. But i am having a small issue i.e i would like to set the `Start year` from `1900` and `End year` to `Current Year` or `9999`..

In the script i found this for `year range`

```
yearRange: 'c-100:c+100'
```

If i move forward to some thing like `1800` i am unable to see the `current year`.. What changes should i do here in order to see my years in a such a way that the years should be `1900-current year` or `1900-9999`

I tried this which works for me but as it is loading when the calendar loads it taking much time when my application runs

```
 datepick({yearRange: '1900:9999'});
```

So any better option than this  to achieve as per my requirement

Comment: I'm just interested why you need to have the ability to select dates from the year 9999?

Comment: You're already doing what the Datepicker doco says to do ('1900:9999'). Can you explain in more detail why this isn't working for you? And what is your criteria for deciding whether you want the upper limit to be the current year or 9999?

Comment: It is not mandatory to have `9999` at least i would like to select up to `current year` it's enough.. But as per the `Jquery plugin` if we move forward of years the later years are not shown i.e my issue

Comment: `nnnn` that works but when my application was big on clicking the select date the calendar is loading lazy that's why i am looking for alternative

Comment: For birthdates see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269545/jquery-datepicker-years-shown

Answer (score 32):

try this:

```
datepick({yearRange: '1900:' + new Date().getFullYear()});
```

Comment: That's I was looking for use in case of date of birth.

Answer (score 11):

```
$("#textBox").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: '1900:+0'
});
```

Answer (score 5):

This is what you need:

```
datepick({yearRange: "1900:+nn"});
```

Will set the range from the 1900 to the current year.

Comment: if you select 2000 after then the range will change to 1900:2000, and you can't return to the current year

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following.

```
 $("#datepicker").datepicker({
     changeMonth: true, // this will help you to change month as you like
     changeYear: true, // this will help you to change years as you like
     yearRange: "1900:9999"
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

$("#date").datepicker({
    changeYear:true,
    yearRange: "1900:1999"
    });

Answer (score 0):

you can set specific year of difference from current year

```
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
        changeYear: true,
         minDate: '-116Y',
         maxDate: '1Y', 
         yearRange: '-116',
     });
```