# Jquery datepicker, select year

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I would like to have more than 11 dates to choose from, instead I'd like to have all possible years in one single dropdown

This is my code:

```
$( function() {
    $( "#data" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: "-100Y",
        maxDate: "-18Y"
    });
} );
```

I would like to have full selection from 1917 to 1999

[image: date picker]

Comment: maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211591/how-can-i-set-year-range-for-a-jquery-date-picker-1900-to-current-year-or-1900

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```js
$(function() {
  $("#data").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "-100:-18"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="data" />
```